# JCo | How to iterate column wise

Tags: java, jco

The data from SAP is returned as a `JCo.Table`.
However, we don't want to display ALL the columns in the VIEW.
So, what we have done is, we have created a file called `display.xml` which has the `JCO.Table` columns to be displayed.

The `display.xml` is converted to a `List<DisplayFieldDto>` and **each field** is verified if it is present in the display list (see the code below) which is redundant from second row onwards, as shown in the code below.

What is the better way to filter the fields in JCo?
Can I iterate column wise?
Thank you :)

```
final Table outputTable = jcoFunction.getTableParameterList().
                    getTable("OUTPUT_TABLE");
    final int numRows = outputTable.getNumRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {         
        final FieldIterator fields = outputTable.fields();
        while (fields.hasNextFields()) {
           final JCO.Field recordField = fields.nextField();
           final String sapFieldName = recordField.getName();
           final DisplayFieldDto key = new DisplayFieldDto(sapFieldName);
           if (displayFields.contains(key)) {
               System.out.println("recordField.getName() = " 
                          + recordField.getName());
               final String sapFieldName = (String)recordField.getValue();      
           } else {
            // ignore the field.
           }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of getting all fields of the table record and checking them against fields present in displayFields, you could take only the fields of the record that are in displayFields. 
The following code suppose that displayFields is a List of String

```
for (int i = 0; i < ouputTable.getNumRows(); i++) {
   outputTable.setRow(i);
   Iterator it = displayField.iterator();
   // get fields of current record
   while(it.hasNext()){
      String fieldName = (String)it.next();
      String value = outputTable.getString(fieldName);
      // do what you need to do with the field and value
   }
}
```

hope this helps,
Regards,
Guillaume